# Divs don't collapse as they should - media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working with tutorial about responsive website design but I don't have any idea why this code isn't working properly.

[Link to tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_fhyXUH_To)

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmm5p/) and code. Where is the problem? How to make right div to go under left when resize window?

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="containter">
    <img src="http://cf.badassdigest.com/_uploads/images/28150/alternate_oscars_header__index.jp"/>
    <div id="left-column"> This is the left column. Staphp dap trap dap tyryt Staphp dap trap dap</div>
    <div id="right-column"> make blablabala and kitcat Staphp dap trap dap tyryt  Staphp dap trap dap tyryt </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 600px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#left-column {
width: 400px;
float: left;
background: red; 
}
#right-column {
width: 200px;
float: right;
background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {
#container {
width:100%
}
#left-column {
width: 70%;
float: left;
background: red; 
}
#right-column {
width: 30%;
float: right;
background: green;
}
img {
width: 100%
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
#left-column {
width: 100%
background: red; 
}
#right-column {
width: 100%
background: green;
}
}
```

Random text about nothing because I have no more details.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question - to describe the specific problem you are having. I doubt that anyone wants to work through the tutorial just to answer an un-stated question.

Comment: I've added specific question. I've thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you meant that your image and your divs aren't resizing as planed, which happened because you had faulty CSS. At line 32, 38 and 42 was a ';' missing. My tip is to use a [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) if you get stuck with tutorial code most of the times it's something little as this. Here your [fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmm5p/4/) btw.
I wish you good luck and fun, Sam!

```
#container {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#left-column {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    background: red; 
}

#right-column {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    #container {
        width:100%
    }

    #left-column {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        background: red; 
    }

    #right-column {
        width: 30%;
        float: right;
        background: green;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #left-column {
        width: 100%;
        background: red; 
    }

    #right-column {
        width: 100%;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @sternAndy for the JSfiddle. Always nice to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled container in your HTML `<div id="containter">`

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now it's much better but right div still doesn't want to go under left one

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case of CSS typos, you are missing a few properties separators ';'. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/fmm5p/3/) the corrected (working) fiddle.

Specifically, this one was causing the max-width property issue

```
@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
   #left-column {
   width: 100%; 
   background: red; 
}
```

Comment: tomaroo is also right about the typo in the container element id, but that's a different issue... :)

Comment: Now it's fully working! I think it's too late for me ;) I can't accept two answers, so i give you both (@tomaroo) points.